# Creating unknown number of objects with each having specific object name at runtime c++

Tags: c++, loops, scope, object-lifetime

I want to create an unknown number of objects each with a specific object name inside the main-method at runtime. The objects should be existent until the program ends (main-method ends). Note, that in my case the objects are Fields.

I thought about a solution like this:

```
for ( i=1 ; i <= NumberOfObjects ; i++)
{

if (i==1)
{
MyClass *ObjectName1 = new MyClass();

}

if (i==2)
{
MyClass *ObjectName2 = new MyClass();

}

.   //more if statements for more objects
.
.

} //for loop closed
```

Questions:

1. I don't think this solution is good, since the number of created objects still would be limited to the if-statements within the for-loop. Any better solutions?
2. Scope of pointers in loops: When the if-blocks are exited the pointers are out of scope. How can I access the with "new" created objects afterwards?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this? There is almost certainly a better approach.

Comment: Just use a std::map and store each new object with a generated key which will "name" it.

Comment: No offense, but I'm tempted to upvote this question for it's amazing Noob'ness :-D

Comment: you cant, in c++ after compilation object does not have names

Comment: @JBentley: the number of objects (fields) that need to be created is read out of a file and this number is decided by the programs user...

Comment: @Martin Ba: I am just searching for a solution to this problem. Nobody knows everything...

Comment: @Streight No I mean why you need the objects to be named.

Comment: @JBentley: Because each object (field) represents a different physical dimension, giving it a proper name makes the code much more easy to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Named variables are removed once the code is compiled and doesn't mean anything to you afterwards.

Looks like you need a look up table, use an std::map or std::unordered_map with string key as the name of the object.

```
std::map<std::string, MyClass*> variablesTable;
for ( i=1 ; i <= NumberOfObjects ; i++)
{
    std::ostringstream oss << "name" << i;
    variablesTable[oss.str()] = new MyClass();    //you actually need to check if it exists, otherwise will be overwritten.
}
```

As if you want each created to run a separate code for each object, you can have a table of function objects (or just store both in a tuple) like this `std::map<std::string, std::<MyClass, Func>>.`

If you want to lookup just use,

```
MyClass* object = variablesTable[strName];
object->CallFunction();
```

P.S. A known trick for hash_maps is to run script before building the project to convert any literal string to int, because comparing int is faster than strings. At least I know this was used in the Uncharted series (but hardly relevant to your case).

Comment: Could you tell me what "auto" exactly is? As far as I understand you are creating the pointer "object" of type "auto" that points to the element of the map with name "strName", afterwards you use a method "CallFunction()" on object. I don't get this :)

Comment: @Streight I just changed it. auto is a new keyword in C++11 where it can deduce the type. if you are using compiler that doesn't support C++11 you can't use auto. simply replace auto with the type returned from the right side of the expression

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on your approach, there is no need for a loop. You can simplify this to

```
MyClass *ObjectName1 = new MyClass();
MyClass *ObjectName2 = new MyClass();
MyClass *ObjectName3 = new MyClass();
...
```

The scope and the lifetime of the pointer already ends, when you leave the `if` statement. To access the pointers outside the if/for statements, you have to move them before the loop.

I would just use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of objects

```
std::vector<MyClass*> objects;
for (int i = 1; i <= NumberOfObjects; i++) {
    MyClass *p = new MyClass();
    objects.push_back(p);
}
```

This won't give you an individual name for each object, but is maintainable at least.

*Update:*

To address the concerns of leaking memory, you can also create the objects directly in the vector without an explicit new

```
std::vector<MyClass> objects;
for (int i = 1; i <= NumberOfObjects; i++)
    objects.push_back(MyClass());
```

This will give you the objects and they will be cleaned automatically, when the scope of the vector ends.

Comment: Whilst this is probably a better solution to his problem, it doesn't actually answer the question and should be a comment.

Comment: Also, your version without the loop or `if` statements doesn't allow for the number of objects to be decided at runtime

Comment: Of course, that's still leaking the memory to these objects.

Comment: @MartinBa What is leaking memory? The objects are still referenced from the vector.

Comment: Should p be created as a pointer? `objects.push_back(p)` will fail. Also, yo can do `MyClass p` **before** the for loop and set `p=MyClass()` inside it, so that way you're not creating a new p in every iteration.

Comment: @OlafDietsche You're newing up objects (`new MyClass()`) but they're never cleaned up.

Comment: @MartinBa The question is about creating not destroying objects. And as the OP said, this is in main. So when main ends, the operating system already cleans up any memory used.

Comment: That `push_back()` will fail. You can't push a pointer inside an 'object' vector. Also, when you do `p = MyClass();` you're actually creating a new instance, you don't need to declare the type again. The last object you created is at this time stored into the vector.

Comment: Why would you make the switch to storing a vector of pointers, which require manual cleanup, instead of just creating and stroring the objects properly as values, and letting the vector destructor clean them up for you?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: While the answer has been improved, I still feel I can't remove my downvote as it ignores the basic requirement of the question - the OP wants to be able to create an **arbitrary** number of named objects, with the number to be decided at runtime. So far, disco beat's comment on the question is the only actual solution proposed.

Comment: @JBentley Well, this is debatable. If you restrict yourself to alphabetical names, this is certainly true. I consider numerical names equally valid, YMMV.

Comment: @OlafDietsche What do you mean by numerical names? An index to a `std::vector` is not a name...

Comment: @JBentley: The vector's name, combined with the index (and the associated square brackets), is a name. In the sense that it is a word (a sequence of characters) which is used to stand for a thing. (I'm not arguing that this is a good answer, btw, just clarifying what I think Olaf means when he refers to numerical names)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You're talking about the English language definition of the word "name", which is not the same as the C++ term "name", which is an identifier used to refer to a declared entity. EDIT: Yes, I take your point.

Comment: @JBentley: The same applies to `operator[]` on a `std::map`, which you remarked (in reference to disco beat's comment) to be an actual solution (and I agree).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Good point. I'll remove my downvote on that basis.

Comment: @JBentley While using a `map` is a technically feasible solution and answers the OP's question, it does come with a cost. Especially when you name it with `string`s, which involve an additional memory allocation. However, if you answer the problem instead, and consider showing an alternative solution, I think this is still the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need something to store that objects. For example you could use a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), or a [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map). You can store an unlimited number of objects (actually you're limited by your memory amount, let's say **almost** unlimited) inside these data structures, without caring about the memory since it's managed automatically.

Comment: Reasons for my downvote: (1) `std::vector` won't allow the OP to name his objects, (2) `std::map` will but more work will be required to come up with the names, and you haven't explained how the OP should use it, (3) the comment about unlimited / almost unlimited is inappropriate since we don't know what memory constraints the OP is working with or how big his objects are.

Comment: I'll look for my flagellation instruments.

Comment: @JBentley: the naming requirement is unclear: OP uses `ObjectName1` whereas `ObjectName[0]` seems equivalent.

Comment: @jarod42 I don't think it's unclear. I agree that the OP probably **should** use something like `ObjectName[0]`, but his question as currently phrased asks for individual named objects.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: OK, that's not an answer. OP wants arbitrary object count at run time!
That question may be a template meta programming one.

Use a vector to store the pointer, use a macro to define a new pointer and push it to the vector.
Before ending, use the vector to free.

```
#include <vector>

#define DEFVAR( varname )      \
    foo* varname = new foo();  \
    v.push_back( varname )

class foo {};

int main() {

   std::vector<foo*> v;

   DEFVAR( ObjName1 );
   DEFVAR( ObjName2 );
   DEFVAR( ObjName3 );
   DEFVAR( ObjName4 );

   [ .... ]

   for ( size_t index = 0; index < v.size(); ++index ) delete v[ index ];

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: If you're going to hard code the number of objects and their names, why not do it directly in code? I don't see what purpose the macro serves here, or how it solves the OP's problem.

Comment: @JBentley I just wanted to combine a simple definition/naming instruction with the "one line" delete(s) at the end.